# Initial miles on car

Tags: honda, mileage

I recently purchased a car from a Honda Dealer. I see that the odometer reading is already 230 miles. When I asked them about this, they replied saying that it was because the vehicle is transferred from another lot.

Should I be worried about the 230 miles driven?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: In the UK there is a specific term for this that you'll see in the car adverts - "delivery mileage"

Answer (score 17):

tl dr: **No.**

Over the lifespan of your vehicle, 230 miles is absolutely nothing (especially on Hondas, lol). At most, this *starts* to get you to the break in point of the engine. You'll still need to keep the regular maintenance on the car at the given points, but overall it really means nothing.

As far as warranty goes, it doesn't start until the car is purchased. If the car was a demo model (say the owner of the dealership was using it) and it had 1500 miles on it, the warranty starts when the vehicle is sold. It is in essence considered a "new car". The dealership puts this mileage and date information into the Honda database and this is the point at which things start counting.

Comment: So if the car has a 15k mile warranty, the warranty is good until the odometer reads 15,230 miles?

Comment: @Acccumulation - That's the way it works in the States. I'm sure you're just throwing a number out there, but I've never seen an auto warranty that low (15k). Even the Bumper-to-Bumper coverage is a minimum 36k/3yrs these days.

Comment: That assumption is not correct for all brands. BMW for example will set the in-service date to the date of first retail (so it doesn't matter how long it sits on the lot before purchase) you get 4 years of warranty from that date **OR** a hard 50,000 mile limit... doesn't matter what was on the odo when you bought it, it still runs out at 50k.

Comment: @CactusCake - Maybe true for BMW, but it's not what I experienced with many different brands when I sold cars (as far as mileage goes). Not an assumption, but rather experience is what I'm going on here.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning those brands then, since most [sources I'm finding](https://itstillruns.com/pros-cons-buying-demo-vehicle-7745979.html) suggest you get extra time based on when it sells, [but not extra miles](https://www.consumerreports.org/cro/news/2009/03/what-is-the-real-deal-with-buying-a-demo-car/index.htm). (Hmm, in some cases you [don't even get the extra time](http://www.realcartips.com/newcars/065-buying-demo-cars.shtml) ).

Comment: @CactusCake - Well, so be it. Again, not what I've seen. If you are getting a discount on the vehicle due to the miles, it would make sense you wouldn't get the additional miles on the warranty. In the past, I'd sold Mazda, Kia, Hyundai, Mercury, Lincoln, Mitsubishi, GMC, Pontiac, Buick, and Isuzu. All of them started from when the vehicle was sold, not from a zero mark.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't worry about it - "new" cars quite often accumulate a few miles pre-delivery. Usually this is the vehicle being moved between lots (as the dealer said) and various movements around storage facilities. A friend of mine has worked for some time at the main Jaguar Landrover factory here in the UK and from what he has described cars get moved around the extensive site quite frequently so if this was a car you bought from stock as opposed to a specific factory order then it will easily have accumulated a fair few while it was in storage.

230 miles is above average but could easily be accounted for by transferring the car without the aid of a car transporter, this wouldn't be unreasonable in the circumstances where it was the only car being transferred at that time and there wasn't a suitable transporter available or if they were looking to save on the expense. Especially if it was coming from dealer stock as sending a driver to move it between sites is going to be far, far cheaper than using a truck.

Some manufacturers actually accommodate this sort of thing by allowing one-time "resets" to the odometer before delivery, this is usually controlled by a combination of the limited use nature and a maximum mileage in order to prevent abuse from those seeking to "clock" the car. It's highly unlikely that those 230 miles are going to make one iota of difference to the condition of the car or anything like that. If you are otherwise happy with the car then I'd just chalk it up as a curiosity and move on.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you already paid for the thing and there's not typically a huge window of time to return it, the answer to your stated question, according to the Serenity Prayer, is to accept with serenity the things you cannot change.

What you may also be asking however, is "is there a legitimate reason to have so many miles on a car that hasn't been owned before?"

Yes.

It could have been from moving cars from dealer to dealer, but in my somewhat limited experience that happens on a car hauler-- especially if we're talking about another lot 3+ hours away, unless you live absolutely in the middle of nowhere.

The miles aren't high enough for it to have been a "demo car" that a dealership employee uses, so my guess would be that someone took it for an extended test drive, like over a weekend.

Another thing that would sometimes add miles is the pre-delivery inspection, but we're looking at maybe one or two miles.

Answer (score 1):

Another source for the miles is test drives.  Consider how many miles you put on the car during your test drive, then think about how many other people may have done the same.  Unless you ordered the car from the factory (which it doesn't sound like you did), there's been at least a few test drives, along with un/load from any transport semis, basic movement around the dealership lot, and other short "trips" that eventually can add up.

As others said, this usually isn't something to be concerned with.  The only time I would be concerned is if there's Something Wrong with it, which I'm assuming isn't the case, since you bought it.